# Does anyone know where I can find current information on adding h2 persistence to a RCP e4 app?

Tags: persistence, rcp, e4

I would like to add some persistence to save some application data and I feel like I have searched the web for days without any success.

I have found some older links and the eclipse Gemini project. However, I suppose I am too new to understand the implementation or it is just a little dated. Probably, more of my lack of knowledge.

Anyway, is anyone willing to point me to a working example and/or provide me with some assistance offline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use H2 with plain JDBC, you won't need the Gemini project. In this case you can wrap the H2.jar with the corresponding JDBC driver in a single bundle (plugin) and implement your db access there.

The Gemini project is for using persistence via JPA, which works with any JDBC capable database.

In either case, be aware that in an OSGi environment like Eclipse RCP, there is one classloader per bundle. This leads to lots of complications. We are using Hibernate as JPA engine within our E4 application and we cannot split the JPA configuration, the JPA engine and the entity beans :-(
We tried using EclipseLink as JPA engine but this doesn't work on all our entities :-(

I found this [blog article by Raja Kannappan](http://rajakannappan.blogspot.de/2010/03/eclipse-classloading-and-buddy-policy.html) which briefly explains class loading in OSGi.

You can read more about JPA in [The Java EE Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm#BNBPY) (although JPA is part of Java SE, too).

Hope this helps.